# Change case of line not matching a pattern

Tags: linux, sed, pattern-matching, substitution

I have a large file in this format:

>Abc1 | SOME TEXT

atgcgnntcagacagacaa

>Abc2 | SOME DIFFERENT TEXT

nnatgcgatgacatacanggaaga

>Abc3 | SOME OTHER TEXT

gcatgacagagacagatgacaggcacacg

All I am trying to do is change the case of line not starting with '>Abc'. Simple it seems but I do not know why it is not working:

```
sed -n '/^>/! y/atgcn/ATGCN/' sequence.fa > test2
```

I would appreciate your help.

AK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `-n` switch from the command

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do things:

```
sed '/^>/!s/./\u&/g' sequence.fa > test2
```

Comment: `sed '/^>/!s/.*/\U&/' sequence.fa > test2` might do too